# get keys when request filter

Tags: php, laravel

I filter request that removes null parameters,
now I want to get keys parameters that not null.

like that:

```
$data = collect(request()->keys())->filter()->all();
        $data->keys();
        return $data;
```

Comment: I don't think `collect(request()->keys())->filter()` does what you think it does. It will remove all null keys from the request, but I don't think it's ever possible a key to be null in a request. That's unlikely. Maybe you can do `collect(request()->all())->filter()->keys()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$parameters = [];
foreach($request->all() as $parameter) {
    if (!is_null($parameter)) {
        $parameters[] = $parameter
    }
}
```